# Pst-Solides3D Transformation of a Cube with parameter

Tags: pstricks, 3d, pst-solides3d

I'm working on the example given at 4.14.3. in the documentation on Pst-Solides3d : Transformation associated with the distance to the origin.

The code is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[english,verbose]{layout}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-4)(4,3) 
\psset{viewpoint=20 60 20 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=10 15 7, 
Decran=20} 
 \pstVerb{ 
 /gro { 
 4 dict begin 
 /M defpoint3d 
 /a 0.5 def 
 /b 1 a 3 sqrt mul sub def 
 /k M norme3d a mul b add def 
 M k mulv3d 
 end 
 } def}% 

 \psset{linewidth=.02,linecolor=gray} 
 \psSolid[object=cube,a=3,ngrid=9,transform=gro](0,0,0)% 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

And transforms the cube accordingly. What I would like, is to be able to parameterize the procedure in a loop, for the parameter \a.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[english,verbose]{layout}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\multido{\iA=0+1}{15}{%
\FPeval{\iB}{\iA*0.5/15}%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-4)(4,3) 
\psset{viewpoint=20 60 20 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=10 15 7, 
Decran=20} 
 \pstVerb{ 
 /gro { 
 4 dict begin 
 /M defpoint3d 
 /a \iB\space def 
 /b 1 a 3 sqrt mul sub def 
 /k M norme3d a mul b add def 
 M k mulv3d 
 end 
 } def}% 
 \psset{linewidth=.02,linecolor=gray} 
 \psSolid[object=cube,a=3,ngrid=9,transform=gro](0,0,0)% 
\end{pspicture}
\newpage
}
\end{document}
```

So that the parameter a varies from 0 to 0.5 (modulo 1 increment..) in 15 steps.
But somehow pst-Solides3d doesn't like it when I put anything else than a number there after /a. Any solution ?

For the sake of being perfectly clear : My goal is to animate a coordinate transformation on a cube. The transformation is given by the function /gro. The target transformed cube has a transformation of parameter /a = 0.5. /a = 0 doesn't transform the cube at all. So my goal is to generate pictures with /a ranging from 0 to 0.5, that is going from untransformed to fully transformed cube. Then I'll use animategraphics to animate the transformation.

Edit: I have figured it out, all I was missing was a \space after \iB.

Comment: +1 nice question; could you turn your snippet into a complete MWE? :)

Comment: I don't know if I understand your comment correctly. I interpreted as you wanting me to expand the shortly written second code. Done :)

Comment: have a look at [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Please present the complete code that is compilable for others to make a test.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post. This is the whole code. The first one works (with pdflatex) the second one won't.

Comment: I have figured it out. I was missing a \space after \iB in my second code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting :) I'll flat it for a moderator, glad you got it fixed :)

Comment: On the basis that a missing `\space` is pretty specific to this question, I've closed 'too localized'.